# Extract tables from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, regex, regex-greedy

I'm trying to extract a list of tables in FROM|JOIN with a regex but I want to exclude all aliases and spaces in order to get only the schema and table (SCHEMA.TABLE).

The following regex do it but I can't exclude the aliases:

`(?i)(?:FROM|JOIN) .*?(.*\..*)( ?\w)$`

SELECT A,B
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE TB
WHERE A=B; --> Return 'SCHEMA.TABLE TB', I want to exclude everything after the table name.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Some tables don't have alias at the end of the line:

Case 1:

```
SELECT A,B
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE TB
WHERE A=B
```

Case 2:

```
SELECT A,B
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
WHERE A=B
```

So the REGEX should work in both cases.

Comment: 1st Question: which one SQL do you use - it doesn't look like ANSI/ISO  SQL?

Comment: Standart SQL (Teradata)

Comment: Consider using a SQL parser. SQL (regardless of dialect) is not a language family that can be parsed properly with regexes, especially since most allow, for example, the use of keywords as identifiers (with proper escaping).

Comment: For example...?

Comment: SO is not for software recommendations, nor do I have a particular parser library to recommend. A quick search tells me there are plenty, though.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I still need help with the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the regex that works:

(?i)(?:FROM|JOIN) .*?(.*.[^ ]\w*)

What is important is the use at the end of \w*, that is selecting only word characters.

Hope this helps!